# Improperly installed or nonexistent brick ties in a wall

Tags: brick

Is there as easy way to repair a brick wall that isn't properly attached to the wall behind it?  There are no cracks inside the house but there is a large vertical gap between the corner brick - these come out further than the wall - and the wall brick.  The brick wall will move slightly when you push against it.  When the house was being bricked I noticed one day that there were no brick ties on the wall.  I called the builder extremely upset and when I came by the house later brick ties were being used.  I don't have any idea how much of the work had been done before I saw they were not using the ties.  All the brick work done is terrible!  My dad was a stone mason so I might be overly picky, but there is mortar falling out in a number of places, patio Colima are not straight, fireplace brick inside has some joints that are more than an inch wide!  If I could afford it I would have it all taken down and redone . . .  The house was built after the original house was destroyed by a tornado.  Lots of shoddy work was done in the area at the time.  Looking back I should never allowed myself to be pressured into accepting such poor quality of workmanship.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the ideal solution if the birckwork is generally poor is to rebuild the wall.

In this case this doens't seem to be an option. To replace existing ties that have problems or sections of the wall where ties are missing you can get drill and fix wall ties. I believe you can get this type of system from [Helifix](http://www.helifix.co.uk/) in the UK but I'm sure similar systems exist around the world. You can get systems that rely on some fairly unattractive face plates but other systems do not rely on this but have a resin bond to the brickwork. You will probably need specialist advice on what the right system for you is and to identify if there are any other issues associated with the poorly constructed wall other than the lack of ties.

Answer (score 0):

If this is work in progress then talk to the builder and get him to redo the work properly.

Withhold some (or all) of the money you owe him until he puts it right.

Take photos of the poor workmanship so you have evidence to back up your claims.

Comment: The work was done in 2000 when the house was built.  The original was destroyed by a tornado.  It was a chaotic time trying to "get back home" so I know we let the builder get by with things that we shouldn't have.  At the time we were bring pressured by the insurance company to move in the new house so they could stop paying our rent; our kids wanted to go "home"; there was a shortage of contractors, workmen, even supplies at times.  The better workers were lured away by promises of more money, contractors were inflating the cost of everything, etc.  Now we are paying the price.

Comment: @Ann - what sort of guarantees (if any) came with the rebuild?